# How to initialize a ALAssetsGroupType constant in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to initialize ALAssetsGroupType constant in Swift (Xcode 6.4.):

```
let groupTypes: ALAssetsGroupType = ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupAll)
```

But It doesn't compile for 32bit devices(ex, iPhone 5) and I get error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but the direct approach is to use the constructor for `Int32` to create a signed `Int32` from a `UInt32`:

```
let groupTypes: ALAssetsGroupType = ALAssetsGroupType(Int32(bitPattern: ALAssetsGroupAll))
```

---

### Explanation

If you option-click on `ALAssetsGroupType` you will see that it is a typealias for `Int`:

```
typealias ALAssetsGroupType = Int
```

But, if you then click on `AssetsLibrary` next to *Declared In* you will see that in the header file it is actually a typedef for `NSUInteger`:

**ALAssetsLibrary.h**

```
typedef NSUInteger ALAssetsGroupType;
```

So, what's going on here?  Why doesn't Swift treat `NSUInteger` as `UInt`? Swift is a strongly typed language, which means you can't just assign a `Int` to an `UInt` without conversion.  To keep our lives simpler and to remove many of those conversions, the Swift engineers decided to treat `NSUInteger` as `Int` which saves a lot of hassle **in most cases**.

The next piece of the mystery is the definition of `ALAssetsGroupAll`:

```
enum {
    ALAssetsGroupLibrary        = (1 << 0),         // The Library group that includes all assets.
    ALAssetsGroupAlbum          = (1 << 1),         // All the albums synced from iTunes or created on the device.
    ALAssetsGroupEvent          = (1 << 2),         // All the events synced from iTunes.
    ALAssetsGroupFaces          = (1 << 3),         // All the faces albums synced from iTunes.
    ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos    = (1 << 4),         // The Saved Photos album.
#if __IPHONE_5_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream    = (1 << 5),         // The PhotoStream album.
#endif
    ALAssetsGroupAll            = 0xFFFFFFFF,       // The same as ORing together all the available group types,
};
```

Note that the comment next to `ALAssetsGroupAll` says `"The same as ORing together all the available group types"`.  Well, `0x3F` would have sufficed, but presumably the author decided to set *all* of the bits just to future proof it in case other options were added in the future.

The problem is that while `0xFFFFFFFF` fits in an `NSUInteger`, it doesn't fit into an `Int32`, so you get an overflow warning on 32-bit systems.  The solution provided above converts the `UInt32` `0xFFFFFFFF` into an `Int32` with the same bitPattern.  That then gets converted to an `ALAssetsGroupType` which is just an `Int`, so on a 32-bit system you get an `Int` with all bits set (which is the representation of `-1`).  On a 64-bit system, the `Int32` value of `-1` gets sign extended to `-1` in 64-bit which sets all 64 bits of the value.

Another way to solve it is to define your own `AllGroups`:

```
let AllGroups = -1  // all bits set
let groupTypes: ALAssetsGroupType = AllGroups
```

Note, this is deprecated in iOS 9:

```
typedef NSUInteger ALAssetsGroupType NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 9_0, "Use PHAssetCollectionType and PHAssetCollectionSubtype in the Photos framework instead");
```

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation in case you were wondering "why"?